# I want to enable g zip compression in php website i have found two way to do it which one more efficient

Tags: php, gzip

i have two methods to do it given below which one is more efficient and and where i need to place . htaccess or some where else

Method 1 :

```
# Enable GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</ifmodule>

# Expires Headers - 2678400s = 31 days
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2678400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2678400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2678400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 518400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds"
</ifmodule>

# Cache Headers
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
  # Cache specified files for 31 days
  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache HTML files for a couple hours
  <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache PDFs for a day
  <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache Javascripts for 31 days
  <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
  </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
```

Method 2

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Well if you want to enable `gzip` you need to use method 2, method one is to enable deflate (zip).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to enable gzip compression is add the code in htaccess. If you have access to the server root and is aware of system settings then enable gzip compression using `httpd-vhosts.conf` files.

Comment: But which code i need to add i have two methods as specified in the description tag  which one is better

Comment: Second method is for enabling gzip compression only. First method enables compression and also sets cache expiry time for static files. If you already set expiry time in any other step then use the second method else use first method.

Comment: if i add the code in httpd-vhosts.conf is it fast than htacess

Comment: also second method have <ifModule mod_gzip.c> and first method have <ifmodule mod_deflate.c> so i have dough how it can be same please check methods one if any thing need to add or remove